# How many hits can an armoured thug take?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In a beatdown attack, how many beatdown hits can an armoured thug take before being finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[14 hits as Catwoman](http://youtu.be/zboeyHIl7CE) (three samples).
[10 hits as Batman (even while juicing, but not switching targets)](http://youtu.be/aBiRiiyu3HQ).

Two theories are that they either get more health as the fight goes on in Joker's Carnival and/or different armored thugs have different health, because—on at least one occasion—[an armored thug took 36 hits](http://youtu.be/w9IwlJt82pQ).

Comment: I guess I was hoping for someone to explain the anomaly.

Comment: Oh ok. It might have just been a glitch, because I've never heard of it happening to anyone else.